# Securing CloudFront Signed URLs

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Let's say I generated a signed url as follows:

```
https://myapp.mydomain.net/media/comicCon.jpg?Key-Pair-Id=XXXXXXXXXXXX&Signature=SomeSignature&Expires=1573770000
```

I have this image on a page in myapp.
Somebody that is logged into myapp could view source and copy the signed url, passing it around to their friends?

I don't want to allow this.

I know you can set short expires and ip address ranges but they are not an option.

Maybe I need to generate a private key every time someone logs into myapp and pass this to call to generate signed url?

Am I missing something obvious about how CloudFront works?

---

We have actually moved to signed cookies instead and can limit by ip.
Created new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49873206/limiting-cloudfront-signed-cookies-by-ip) for problem with creating signed cookie limited by ip.

Comment: I think based on this answer by @JohnRotenstein, that they can be limited by time/ip only.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609663/aws-s3-the-security-of-a-signed-url-as-a-hyperlink

Comment: *"I know you can set short expires and ip address ranges but they are not an option."*  Why not?  You generate the signed links while rendering the page, specifically for that user from their current IP address.

Comment: With CloudFront, you can also embed extra "tattle-tale" info in the signed URL, with arbitrary `x-...` parameters e.g. `?x-authorized-site-user=John+Smith&...`.  CloudFront doesn't understand them, so they have no function, yet if you add them before signing, they are automatically mandatory and immutable: if the user tries to modify them before sharing, the signature no longer matches and the link is unusable -- signed URLs can't be modified by the user.  These values can be used to "discourage" sharing, and they are logged in the CloudFront access logs.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I jumped the gun thinking we could not limit based on ip address, we can. Actually using signed cookies instead.
For some reason using ip address/range in call doesn't seem to work. See updated question..