# view file contents from aws s3 in web browser

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am storing images in the s3 bucket using java spring-boot and storing the file path in the DB. I am giving the path to the client so that they can view the file instead of download it.I am able to generate pre-signed URL for the s3 object. So, that if I give to the client they can view the file contents But if the person shares it with others, they can also view. I want to make this URL as password protected. Is there any way to do it? Or any other way so that client can view the file?

Comment: This is an interesting problem. According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), "Anyone who receives the pre-signed URL can then access the object." This is because when you create a presigned URL, you do so by providing your own credentials, and the only protection that URL has is its expiry date and time.

Comment: Take a look at these resources:
You can, for each of your clients, create a user in AWS with only read permissions to a [particular folder in an S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/), store each client's files in their respective folders, and to and then [use THAT users AWS ID and secret to generate a download link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678835/how-secure-are-amazon-aws-access-keys).

Comment: thanks, @Ishnark, I found another way to get this without using pre-signed URL.

Comment: @ASHVINIKUMAR can you elaborate another way please?