# how can I hide my access key in pre-signed url by aws s3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, access-keys

I am generating pre-signed url on aws s3 using python. ater generating it shows my access key in the url. how can I generate url with showing my access key?

https://console.wasabisys.com/testing-usman/?AWSAccessKeyId=

This is the code i am using:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
endpoint_url = 'https://console.wasabisys.com',
aws_access_key_id = '<4XR7DSJX1MYFYXETUGBA>',
aws_secret_access_key = '<8aD49ac2cJsuWr7crjRTAN0jqH4JzyV6uQwhJyw1>')

url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
ClientMethod='get_object',
Params={
    'Bucket': 'testing-usman',
    'Key': '.'  

   }
)
print(url)
```

I need the url without showing my access key.

Comment: Pre-signed URLs include an access key. You can't avoid this. You could create a second IAM user specifically for the purpose of pre-signing, and limit the permissions of that user.

Comment: [Access Key Id is not secret and does not need protecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7684662/303810).
But if you're worried for some reason, use STS to generate temporary credentials and then use those to create a pre-signed URLs.

Comment: thanks. I think I should go with the second IAM user.

Comment: Much like a username, an access key *is* half of your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a credential to aws, so to looks less explicit you can add to the boto3 client a config:

```
from botocore.client import Config

s3 = boto3.client('s3',
config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
endpoint_url = 'https://console.wasabisys.com',
aws_access_key_id = '<4XR7DSJX1MYFYXETUGBA>',
aws_secret_access_key = '<8aD49ac2cJsuWr7crjRTAN0jqH4JzyV6uQwhJyw1>')
```